# ¿Como puedo solucionar de que el build se me quedo ejecutando?

Tags: java

Resulta que le doy build a mi proyecto de spring boot en netbeans pero no me pase de aca...

```
2023-11-15 23:23:21.520  INFO 14436 --- [           main] c.m.quincho.QuinchoApplicationTests      : Starting QuinchoApplicationTests using Java 11.0.17 on TP-de-QuinS with PID 14436 (started by QuinSDev in C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\Sebas\Proyecto-Final-Egg\mercado-quincho)
2023-11-15 23:23:21.520  INFO 14436 --- [           main] c.m.quincho.QuinchoApplicationTests      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-15 23:23:23.352  INFO 14436 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-15 23:23:23.539  INFO 14436 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 170 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-15 23:23:25.055  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-15 23:23:25.227  INFO 14436 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
2023-11-15 23:23:25.732  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-11-15 23:23:26.265  INFO 14436 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-15 23:23:26.729  INFO 14436 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-15 23:23:26.776  INFO 14436 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

¿Que hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Podrías darle un clean and build

Comment: intenta "apagar" tu base de datos mientras compilas y si falla es que tus pruebas se estaban conectando a la base de datos lo cual es una mala práctica